# Exclude columns in Sqoop

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop2

is there a way in Sqoop to get all the columns except one from SQL Server to Hadoop.
I do not want to write the --query or use --columns as the numbers of columns are more.
There is just one column which is causing the issue and dividing the data into multiple rows, and I don't need that column but need all others. 
What is the best way to handle this? I tried looking for some option to exclude the columns but had no luck. Looking for some pointers here.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a View and Sqoop it.

Using SSMS you can right click and generate SELECT statement, remove that one column and create a View around it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That will help, but I was looking for an option in Sqoop Script, if available